# How to I retrieve a random Id given to a generated EditText and pass it to a String

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I am making an app in which the user will need to generate EditTexts to input data. Here is my code:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
editText.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
sundayLinearLayout.addView(editText);
editText.setHint("New side");
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
editText.generateViewId();
editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
editText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
```

Everytime the user clicks to create a new EditText, I give it a random id. I need some way to identify all of the EditTexts the user makes somehow and pass it to a string or int. How would i do this?

Comment: you can use an array to store the ids of edittext.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the view to any Layout, you can call method .getId()

Then you can convert it into a String and do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you for replying but i still have a question. What would the benefit be of using a tag and how would I then retrieve the editText I'd in order to delete them or save them?

Comment: @SG123 Adding a tag is a possibility to tie an Object with the View. It is used in situations, when your View depends or works with some complex values. In this case you call .setTag() to tie the object and when you need to get it easily, you call .getTag()

Comment: @SG123, if you create views programmatically, you'd better have a variable (global or somewhere where you can easily get it) pointing to those views, and use it when you need to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways. 
First you can store in a List in a random/sequential way. 
Like this:

```
List<EditText> editTextsList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editText = new EditText(context); 
editTextsList.add(editText);
```

or you can identify your views by TAG.

```
List<EditText> editTextsList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editText = new EditText(context);
editText.setTag(randomNumber) // it can be any object
editTextsList.add((int)editText.getTag, new EditText(context)); // in case your tag is an int
```

Comment: What if I need the user to be able to create as many views as possible. Then I would need to be able to save all the text in those views probably through the array list that I created, but how would I be able to point to all values in the list or say of the user wanted to delete the 3rd editText but keep the 4th one and so on? How would this be done.